# jf rt go build not uploading dependencies to jfrog artifactort

Tags: go, devops, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I am trying to build a GO project with JFROG CLI. I have installed jfrod cli and have set-up a sample go project.

When i run jf rt go build the dependencies are being downloaded, but not being uploaded to jfrog artifactory. Please let me know if i am going wrong anywhere on configurations.

git clone https://github.com/jbaruch/artifactory-go-example.git

I have configured jfrog cli and configuration is as below :-

**jf config show**

```
Server ID:                      demo-go-repo-local
JFrog platform URL:             http://172.30.149.181:8081/
Artifactory URL:                http://172.30.149.181:8081/artifactory/
Distribution URL:               http://172.30.149.181:8081/distribution/
Xray URL:                       http://172.30.149.181:8081/xray/
Mission Control URL:            http://172.30.149.181:8081/mc/
Pipelines URL:                  http://172.30.149.181:8081/pipelines/
User:                           admin
Password:                       ***
Default:                        true
```

**cat /root/dir/artifactory-go-example/.jfrog/projects/go.yaml**

```
version: 1
type: go
resolver:
  repo: demo-go-repo-remote
  serverId: demo-go-repo-local
deployer:
  repo: demo-go-repo-local
  serverId: demo-go-repo-local
```

**jf rt go build **

```
11:35:42 [Warn] You are using a deprecated syntax of the command.
        The new command syntax is quite similar to the syntax used by the native go client.
        All you need to do is to add 'jf' as a prefix to the command.
        For example:
        $ jf go ...
        The --build-name and --build-number options are still supported.
11:35:42 [Info] Using go: go version go1.19.2 linux/amd64

go: downloading rsc.io/quote v1.5.2
go: downloading rsc.io/sampler v1.3.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/text v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c
```

NOT uploading to jfrog artifactory in above logs also.

```
cat go.mod
module github.com/you/hello

require rsc.io/quote v1.5.2
```

The dependencies rsc.io/quote and rsc.io/sampler v1.3.0 are not being send to artifactory. If i use go-publish then, the module github.com/you/hello is being uploaded to artifactory. Actually, i am looking to upload each dependency in go-mod file also.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `jf go-publish <version>` command, which is also mentioned in the [example project](https://github.com/jbaruch/artifactory-go-example) you cloned.
The `jf go build` command only runs `go build` to build your module, it doesn't publish it to Artifactory. Run the following in your terminal to see the usage help of these commands:

```
jf help go
jf help go-publish
```

Please note that the example project is already 4 years old and somewhat out-dated. It is better to refer to the official JFrog documentation, specifically:

- [QuickStart Guide: Go](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/QuickStart+Guide%3A+Go)
- Artifactory as [Go Registry](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Go+Registry)
- [CLI for JFrog Artifactory - Building Go Packages](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-BuildingGoPackages)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Actually if i try go-publish the whole go module is added to artifactorty.  I wanted the dependencies to be send to artifactorty.

Comment: This is the expected behavior. Publishing dependencies to the local repo using something like "--deps=ALL" or "--publish-deps" was an old behavior that was removed (see release notes for v2.0.0: https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/blob/v2/RELEASE.md#200-july-4-2021). You should resolve your dependencies from a virtual repository containing the remote and local repo, and publish only your own artifacts to the local repo. The remote repo caches your dependencies in Artifactory.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @yinon. If pushing to local artifactory has been removed, what's the process to get the dependencies to syn/move from virtual dev artifactory to staging artifactory?

any input or reference will be appreciated as i am pretty new to Jfrog.

Comment: The usual setup is to have remote Go repositories (e.g. proxy.golang.org) for resolving and caching your 3rd party dependencies, and use them for all stages. Only your own artifacts should be stored in Artifactory local repos - usually a repo per stage, e.g. "go-dev-local", "go-stage-local", "go-prod-local". Use virtual repositories to simplify and consolidate the resolution of dependencies. See: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Onboarding+Best+Practices%3A+JFrog+Artifactory , and: https://jfrog.com/whitepaper/best-practices-structuring-naming-artifactory-repositories/